# Combining parameter with a string in MySql Like Statement

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am creating a jasper report using Jaspersoft Studio 6.0.
I have made a query which is working fine and has the following like statement:
`AND im.item_code LIKE CONCAT('%','BB','%')`

This lists all the rows having the letters BB in the item_code column. This is OK , now I want the users to be able to pick a string.  I want to prompt the user for that string and put it nto a parameter: $P{IC}.  I am not able to create the LIKE statement with the parameter IC.

I have tried `CONCAT('%',$P{IC},'%')`  and also  `CONCAT('%','$P{IC}','%')`
I have also tried  - `LIKE ('%' + '$P!{IC}' + '%')`.
All these did not work.

While searching online I came across the following: `like '%'||'$P!{Parameter1}'||' %'` 
When I do like this, The report simply lists all the rows of im.item_code

Can anyone please help me with this predicament?
Other then LIKE statement, can any other SQL statement be used to achieve the above requirement

A related question: What is the difference between $P{IC} and $P!{IC} parameter statements

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The $P!{...} contains SQL query (whether a query as a whole [select statement or partial one] by replacing SQL query to Parameter syntax .
You can put like

```
"some field ="+"'test'"
```

$P!{...} is like a placeholder for putting additional query.

So, you can have a query

```
"select * from employee where firstName=$P{first_name} and $P!{extended_query}"
```

In $P!{extended_query} you can put like

```
"lastname ="+"'Jackson'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `LOCATE()` Function is a possible solution for your Problem.

```
AND LOCATE($P{IC}, im.item_code) > 0;
```

This should work similar as your `AND im.item_code LIKE CONCAT('%','BB','%')`